# Falcon language reserved keywords

Tags: compiler-construction, keyword, lexical-analysis, falcon

I'm writing a compiler for Falcon (as a course project for my graduate level compiler's class). Currently I'm working on lexical analyser. In that I need to figure out whether a lexeme is a keyword or an identifier. I'm unable to find a list of all reserved keywords for Falcon. For languages like C, C++ it is easily available on either on Wikipedia pages or some standard books.

One dirty hack I did was I downloaded vim syntax file for Falcon to figure out all keywords but I got around 70 words by this method but I read somewhere that Falcon has around 30 keywords like C. I also looked at Falcon's reference manual but there is also I couldn't find a compiled list of all keywords at one place. Does anyone know where I can get the list of all keywords for Falcon?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until they finish (or start) writing their [Language Reference](http://www.falconpl.org/index.ftd?page_id=sitewiki&prj_id=_falcon_site&sid=wiki&pwid=Home&wid=Documentation), I don't really see what you can do other than reverse-engineer their parser. Note that the link on that page doesn't work, that being the point.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I'll give a shot for reverse-engineering! But as a newbie, I don't know how difficult that will be!! Anyway, thank you.